# GoogleストリートビューAPIでインドアビューを除外したい

Tags: google-maps

やりたいことは表題の通りなのですが以下に詳細を付け加えておきます。

■作りたいもの
対象のお店をストリートビューで表示させることです。件数が数万件に及ぶのでAPIで対応したいと考えています。

■やっていること
グーグルストリートビューAPIでお店のジオコードの最寄りのストリートビュー対象エリア（道路）を取得。そこから対象の建物の方角を取得して表示。

■問題点
都内のお店はインドアビューを設定されているところが多く、最寄りのストリートビュー対象地点としてインドアビューが表示されてしまいます。

■解決したいこと
ストリートビューAPIでインドアビューを除外するような方法は有るのでしょうか？

お手数ですが、もしお分かりになるようでしたらご教授の程、よろしくお願いいたします。